# Realistic Lego car sets containing gearboxes and engines?

Tags: technic, sets, vehicle

[Lego Technic 853/956 Auto Chassis](http://technicopedia.com/853.html) contains a car chassis, complete with a transmission gearbox. Other sets like [Lego Technic 858/8858 Auto Engines](http://technicopedia.com/858.html) contain parts to build working models of real-life Inline engines, V6 engines, Boxer engines, and 2-cycle engines.

Most Lego cars are unrealistic as they only have wheels and axles. I am looking for sets that contain a chassis, a transmission gearbox, and an engine. In other words, I am looking for Lego sets that model real cars. Are there any such sets in the 21st century?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**LEGO sets**

There are more than one set with such characteristics. While first four are from 20th century, I've included them anyway, since they are well-known and include characteristics you are interested in.

Let's begin with [8860 - Car Chassis](http://www.technicopedia.com/8860.html) from 1980. This model has steering, 4-cylinder engine, 3-speed transmission, adjustable seats, rear suspension, differential:

[image]

The second one is [8865 - Test Car](http://www.technicopedia.com/8865.html) with steering, V4 engine, 3-speed transmission, adjustable seats, 4 wheel suspension, differential, retractable headlights:

[image]

Next is [8880 - Super Car](http://www.technicopedia.com/8880.html) from 1994 with 4-wheel steering, V8 engine, 4-speed synchronized transmission, 4 wheel independent suspension, 3 differentials, all-wheel drive:

[image]

Then [8448 - Super Street Sensation](http://www.technicopedia.com/8448.html) from 1999 with steering, V8 engine, 5-speed synchronized transmission with reverse, suspension, differential:

[image]

Now moving forward to the 21st century.

[8466 - 4 X 4 Off-Roader](http://www.technicopedia.com/8466.html) is the first set from 2001 with steering, V8 engine, 5-speed synchronized transmission with reverse, suspension, 4 wheel drive:

[image]

[42056 - Porsche 911 GT3 RS](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42056-1) from 2016 has steering, rear flat 6 engine, rear-wheel drive, 4-speed synchronized with reverse and paddle shifting, suspension:

[image]

[42048 - Race Kart](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42048-1) from 2016 is another, while small model, but still has 1 cylinder engine and 2-speed gearbox:

[image]

[42083 - Bugatti Chiron](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42083-1) from 2018 comes with steering, rear W16 engine, 8-speed gearbox with paddle shifting, suspension:

[image]

[42110 - Land Rover Defender](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42110-1) from 2019 with steering, in-line 6 engine, 4-speed sequential gearbox, suspension:

[image]

[42115 - Lamborghini Sián FKP 37](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42115-1) from 2020. It has steering, W12 engine, 8-speed sequential transmission with paddle shifting, suspension:

[image]

And the latest addition - [42143 - Ferrari Daytona SP3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42143-1) from 2022. It has steering, V8 engine, 8-speed sequential transmission with paddle shifting, suspension:

[image]

**LEGO MOCs**

In case you are not limiting yourself to LEGO sets there is another option - MOCs produced by AFOLs. You can find them mostly on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/). There are a lot of creations based on real-life vehicles with functions sometime (quite often for larger models) exceeding those you can find in LEGO sets. Not all of them are as sturdy as LEGO models, but that is a personal preference. Although all of them come with free/paid instructions. Here is an [example of MOCs in Technic theme](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/?get_drill_downs=&min_year=2000&max_year=2020&min_parts=0&max_parts=5000&q=&top_theme=1&inc_premium=on&inc_free=on).

---

Features for sets from early days up to and including 8466 are sourced from [Technicopedia](http://technicopedia.com/). Here you can find animations and more details for each of those sets. Newer sets, sadly, have not been reviewed on Technicopedia.

Comment: let's not forget [8860](http://www.technicopedia.com/8860.html)! this chassis has a four cylinder boxer engine, and a 3-speed unsynchronized transmission gearbox, complete with an ignition distributor and a belt driven cooling fan; full suspension and a differential.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface thanks for pointing this out. Somehow forgot about 8860 set. LEGO prior to 1990 is a bit of a grey area for me.

Comment: You missed the first Car Chassis model (853) from the late 70's. 4 inline engine, 3 speed gearbox (2 forward, 1 reverse), diff, steering and adjustable seats. (No shocks on the rear suspension, slightly predates those.)

Comment: @Tonny OP already mentioned 853 set in his question as an example.

Comment: @Alex I missed that. My bad. There are however 2 cart models 8842 and 948 that I miss. Both have steering and 1 cylinder engine.

Comment: There are 126 sets with Technic Engine Cylinder used to make an engine. It is rather basic functionality. As I understood OP's question, he isn't satisfied with such simplicity and seeks for sets that have at least gearbox. Now this limits the list quite a bit as you can see, as it turns out not that many sets have actual gearbox mimicking real one used for propulsion. Of course there are other sets with gearboxes too, where those are used to drive different functions of a crane, excavator, etc. from a single source (motor). But these doesn't fit the question.

Comment: I had http://www.technicopedia.com/8865.html - 3 speed gearbox, V-4 rear engine, rear differential. It also had rack and pinion steering, which I -- being in the UK -- converted to right-hand drive. It's fairly clearly derived from 8860.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I have no excuses for missing this set. Added now!

Comment: I remember playing with a Technic car that had a working steering wheel when I was a kid in the 90s that I don't think you listed. Not sure if it had engines or a gearbox, though. I think it might have been grey?

Comment: @nick012000 Steering is also very (too) common feature. In just 5 last years 35 models have been made with one or another way of steering. To give you an impression of how many Technic sets have steering - check Brickset (https://brickset.com/sets/tag-Functional-Steering/theme-Technic). Most of these doesn't fit the question, so weren't listed.